# Динамическое изменение масштаба графика, QChart

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside6, qchartview, qchart

Можно ли динамически (крутим `spinbox`) менять масштаб графика?

Минимально воспроизводимый пример (тут только оси, собственно графика тут нет, т.к. не нужен):

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
from PySide6.QtCharts import *
from PySide6.QtGui import *
import sys


class Main(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        chart = MyChart()
        spinbox = MySpinBox()
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(chart)
        vbox.addWidget(spinbox)
        self.setLayout(vbox)


class MyChart(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        chart_view = QChartView()
        chart_view.setRubberBand(QChartView.RectangleRubberBand)
        chart_view.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        layout.addWidget(chart_view)
        chart = QChart()
        chart.setAnimationOptions(QChart.SeriesAnimations)
        series = QLineSeries()
        chart.addSeries(series)
        axis_x = QValueAxis()
        chart.addAxis(axis_x, Qt.AlignBottom)
        series.attachAxis(axis_x)
        axis_y = QValueAxis()
        chart.addAxis(axis_y, Qt.AlignLeft)
        series.attachAxis(axis_y)
        chart_view.setChart(chart)
        self.setLayout(layout)


class MySpinBox(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.chart = MyChart()    # экземпляр класса графика, через него надо менять масштаб
        widget = QSpinBox()
        widget.setMinimum(-100)
        widget.setMaximum(100)
        widget.setSingleStep(1)
        widget.valueChanged.connect(self.value_changed)
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(widget)
        self.setLayout(vbox)

    def value_changed(self, i):
        # Тут надо писать логику изменения масштаба и что-то делать с self.chart
        print(i)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Main()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Это вообще возможно?

Comment: В qt не разбираюсь, но предполагаю, что можно хранить размеры виджета в переменных класса `self.x`, `self.y`, поставить `property` на их изменение, чтобы каждый раз при изменении этих значений, виджет обновлялся. И эти менять значения через property в классе `MySpinBox` как `self.chart.x = ...` и с y аналогично

Comment: Размеры виджета не должны меняться. И даже скроллинг, возможно, не обязателен. Т.е. понятно что нужно переопределение (перерисовка) виджета, но каких именно параметров - не могу понять.

Comment: Да, я вас недопонял, в таком случае, не зная механизма построения графика, ничем помочь не могу

Comment: т.е. та же гугл-карта, но вместо +- работает спинбокс

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пожалуйста, всегда предоставляйте минимально-воспроизводимый пример, который демонстрирует проблему. График также должен быть. И было бы хорошо, если вы как-то показали то, что вы хотите получить.

Ваши изменения и дополнения должны быть в теле вопроса, а не в комментариях.

Я не уверен, что правильно понимаю вас, но мне кажется, что, как вариант, это может выглядеть примерно так:

```
import sys
'''                                                            #  PySide6
from PySide6.QtCore import *
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
from PySide6.QtCharts import *
from PySide6.QtGui import *
'''
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore                     #  PyQt5
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from PyQt5.QtChart import *


class MySpinBox(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
# ?     # экземпляр класса графика, через него надо менять масштаб
# ?     self.chart = MyChart() 
        self.spinBox = QSpinBox()
        self.spinBox.setRange(-15, 15)
        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.addWidget(self.spinBox)


class MyChart(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.chart_view = QChartView()
        self.chart_view.setRubberBand(QChartView.RectangleRubberBand)
        self.chart_view.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)

        chart = QChart()
        chart.setAnimationOptions(QChart.SeriesAnimations)

        series = QLineSeries()
        mas = [
            1.33, 1.15, 1.55, 1.65, 1.64, 1.91, 1.33, 2.3, 1.5, 1.35, 
            2.52, 1.77, 1.7, 1.87, 2.0, 1.55, 1.73, 2.1, 1.33, 1.15, 
            1.55, 1.92, 1.64, 1.91, 1.33, 1.71, 1.5, 1.35, 1.22, 1.77, 
            1.7, 1.87, 2.7, 1.55, 1.73, 2.1,
        ]
        for i in range(0, len(mas)):
            series.append(QtCore.QPointF(i, mas[i]))

        chart.addSeries(series)
        
        self.axis_x = QValueAxis()
        chart.addAxis(self.axis_x, Qt.AlignBottom)
        series.attachAxis(self.axis_x)
        self.axis_y = QValueAxis()
        chart.addAxis(self.axis_y, Qt.AlignLeft)
        series.attachAxis(self.axis_y)
        self.chart_view.setChart(chart)
    
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)        
        layout.addWidget(self.chart_view)

        chart.legend().setMarkerShape(QLegend.MarkerShapeCircle);
        self.chart_view.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing);
        self.chart_view.setRubberBand(QChartView.RectangleRubberBand);
        

class Main(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.chart = MyChart()
        
        self.mySpinBox = MySpinBox()
        self.mySpinBox.spinBox.valueChanged.connect(self.value_changed)
        
        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.addWidget(self.chart)
        vbox.addWidget(self.mySpinBox)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.value = 0                                                # +
        self.zoomFactor = 1.1                                         # +
        
    def value_changed(self, value):
        _value = value - self.value
        self.value = value 
        
        if _value == 1:                          # or Qt.Key_Plus:
            self.chart.chart_view.chart().zoom(self.zoomFactor) 
        elif _value == -1:                       # or Qt.Key_Minus:
            self.chart.chart_view.chart().zoom(1 / self.zoomFactor)
#+ or  
    def keyPressEvent(self, keyEvent):
        key = keyEvent.key()
        if key == Qt.Key_Equal:                             # ----> `=`
            self.chart.chart_view.chart().zoomReset()
            self.mySpinBox.spinBox.setValue(0)
        # ...    
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Main()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]